# Creating GPT partitions with preseed

Tags: ubuntu, gpt, pxe, preseed

I am installing Ubuntu 16.04 with iPXE and trying to create GPT partitions with preseed as follows:

```
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/default_label string gpt
d-i partman-partitioning/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman-partitioning/default_label string gpt
d-i partman/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman/default_label string gpt

d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true

d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/method string regular
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
  boot-root :: \
    1 1 1 free \
    $gptonly{ } \
    $primary{ } \
    $bios_boot{ } \
    method{ biosgrub } \
  . \
  1024 100% 1000000000 ext4 \
    $gptonly{ } \
    $primary{ } \
    $bootable{ } \
    method{ format } format{ } \
    use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
    mountpoint{ / } \
 .
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/no_swap boolean false
d-i debian-installer/add-kernel-opts string nomodeset quiet console=ttyS1,115200n8 console=tty0 elevator=deadline nomodeset

d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
```

The installation completes normal as expected, but the system does not boot after finishing the installation. I tried different options for the recipe i.e:

```
boot-root :: \
  1 1 1 free \
  $gptonly{ } \
  $primary{ } \
  $bios_boot{ } \
  method{ biosgrub } \
. \
200 2 200 ext3 \
  $gptonly{ } \
  $primary{ } \
  $bootable{ } \
  method{ format } format{ } \
  use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext3 } \
  mountpoint{ /boot } \
. \ 
  1024 100% 1000000000 ext4 \
  $primary{ } \
  method{ format } format{ } \
  use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
  mountpoint{ / } \
.
```

the installation breaks with the Error that there is no root file system is defined! I tried many other options by resizing the partitions or using the bootable flag etc., with the same result, the system does not boot or the root file system error during the installation. I ma looking into this for the last three days and have seen and tried many suggested solution with no success! In cases when the installation is successful, I started a live Ubuntu's CD and it shows me the following:

```
~$ sudo fdisk -l
..... 
..... 
..... 
Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: xxxx (replaced real value for simplicity)

Device      Start        End    Sectors    Size    Type
/dev/sda1    2048       4094       2048      1M    BIOS boot
/dev/sda2    4096  488396799  488392704  232.9G    Linux filesystem
..... 
..... 
.....
```

With this recipe:

```
        boot-root ::                                \
        1 1 1 free                                  \
            $gptonly{ }                             \
            $primary{ }                             \
            $bios_boot{ }                           \
            method{ biosgrub }                      \
        .                                           \    
        1024 1024 1000000000 ext4                   \
            $primary{ }                             \
            $bootable{ }                            \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ / }                         \
        .
```

It looks correct but it does not boot! Can someone give me a hint please! Thanks

Comment: Don't know much about those scripts... but for EFI you need one FAT32 partition and it must be minimum 100MiB according to the spec